# Why does [NSDate date] return id?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

Why doesn't it return `NSDate*`?

It's supposed to be a creation function right? All creation function return the class whose type is the class creating it.

Now, I can't do `NSDate.date.timeIntervalSince1970` :(

I thought the compiler is smart enough to know that NSDate.date return NSDate even though the return type is id?

Comment: Because it's 6 characters shorter.

Comment: (Xcode tag? Why? How is this related to Xcode?)

Comment: 4 characters to be precise :-D

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri 6. `NSDate *` versus `id` -> 8 - 2 = 6.

Comment: I didn't count the space and the star :-D

Comment: This is something that has always annoyed me. It makes me angry that clang will happily compile something `NSMutableArray *a = [NSArray array]` without even a warning.

Comment: Oh, all this time NSArray also return id :) I never realized that. So I can't do NSDate.date.timeIntervalSince1970

Comment: @SharenEayrs you shouldn't use dot syntax for non-properties anyways :)

Comment: well, it does make the code looks more neat

Comment: and facebook use it. too bad autocomplete does not work if we do it that way.

Comment: It's supported but not officially supported that kind of thing.

Comment: It's a bad and discouraged practice, since it's confusing. Dot notation should be used for C structs and properties only.

Comment: @JakobEgger: You may be interested in Clang's [`instancetype` return type extension](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#related-result-types), then. Of course, you'll have to wait for Apple to add it to Cocoa, but you can use it in your own classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### UPDATE

Starting from iOS 7, Apple is using `instancetype` as return type for most of the Foundation framework APIs (and other frameworks too), so now for instance the `+date` of `NSDate` has the following signature:

```
+ (instancetype)date
```

I just wrote a [short article](http://www.codepills.net/blog/2013/06/25/type-inference-for-everyone-ios7) about it.

#### Original answer

Constructors and factory methods return `id` in order to allow subclasses to use them without ovverriding.

Imagine you have a subclass of `NSDate` called `NSMutableDate`.

If you call

```
[NSMutableDate date]
```

now you would expect to have a `NSMutableDate *` object back, but if `date` was returning `NSDate *` you would have needed to override that method changing the return type.

Using `id` allows this kind of flexibility.

Actually the clang compiler has the `instancetype` keyword that comes in handy in case you are defining your own factory methods.
I recently talked about this specific issue [here](http://www.codepills.net/blog/2013/01/01/obj-c-infer-types-like-a-man-man/).

Comment: For anyone wondering, there was originally a mutable subclass of NSDate that made use of this method — NSCalendarDate. It has since been superceded by the combination of the individual NSCalendar and NSDate classes.

Answer (score 5):

The class factory methods (such as `[NSMutableDate date]`, `[NSMutableArray array]`, etc.) internally use `alloc`/`init`, and return whatever `init` returns.

`init` and its siblings (`initWith...`) always return an `id`, and by extension, so do the class factory methods.

Answer (score 3):

It's a factory method providing a convenient way of creating new auto-released objects.

See this [Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW36).